# Find conditions on $m$ and $n$ that ensure that $f$ is a bijection.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions, modular-arithmetic

> Given: $X=\{0,1,2,...,m-1\}$, $f:X\to X$,  $f(x)=nx \pmod m$. Find conditions on $m$ and $n$ that ensure that $f$ is a bijection.

#### Progress

It seems that $(m,n)=1$ but I can't prove that. I tried to show that otherwise f is not injective. I assumed that $(m,n)=r>1$ and $m=rm_0$ , $n=rn_0$ . I wanted to show that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\nRightarrow x_1=x_2$. So I got something like $nx_1=nx_2+mk \implies r(x_1-x_2)n_0=rkm_0$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$. But it seems from last equation like it is the same for $r=1$.

Comment: It seems that $(m,n)=1$ but I can't prove that. I tried to show that otherwise f is not injective. I assumed that (m,n)=r>1 and $m=rm_0$ , $n=rn_0$ . I wanted to show that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\nRightarrow x_1=x_2$. So I got something like $nx_1=nx_2+mk \implies r(x_1-x_2)n_0=rkm_0$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$ But it seems from last equation like it is the same for r=1.

Comment: Why do I get so many minuses?

Comment: @Mihail: Try to edit your post by including the work you showed in the comment. Often, people do not bother to read the comments. This should prevent your post from getting further downvotes/getting closed. It is not well received here to not indicate ones own thoughts/problems, partly because this is no homework service site and partly because knowing your thoughts and problems helps others to explain exactly what you need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $X$ is a finite set, so $f: X\to X$ is bijective if and only if it is either one-to-one or onto.  (If it's one, then it's the other.)  So you have your choice--you can work with either condition.

How about this: if $f$ is onto, then there exists some $x \in X$ such that $f(x) = 1$.  That is, $nx = 1 (\textrm{mod } m)$, or in other words, $n$ is invertible mod $m$.  Conversely, suppose $n$ is invertible mod $m$, so $nx = 1$ for some $x$.  Then $f$ is onto: given $y\in X$, take $f(xy) = nxy = 1y = y$.

So, do you know (or can you show) that $n$ is invertible mod $m$ if and only if $gcd(m,n) = 1$? See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse

Comment: I was aware about hint that you proposed. I tried to prove surjectivity and injectivity of f. But I tried to do it in general. I didn't  know that it's enough just to check 1 for surjectivity.
And yes I can prove $nx=1\pmod m \iff \gcd(m,n)=1$:
$nx-1=mk$ for some $k\in \mathbb{N}$. Then $nx-mk=1$ And it is obvious that it is true iff $\gcd(m,n)=1$.